# Unable to hide welcome screen in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to hide the welcome screen.

My `.emacs` file:

```
 (setq c-basic-offset 4) ; indents 4 chars
 (setq tab-width 4)          ; and 4 char wide for TAB
 (setq indent-tabs-mode nil) ; And force use of spaces
 
 (turn-on-font-lock)       ; same as syntax on in Vim
 
 (setq width (max width (+ (length str) 1)))   ;line numbers
 
 (setq inhibit-splash-screen t)         ; hide welcome screen
```

I have tried to run the last line of code in my .emacs unsuccessfully.

How can you hide the welcome screen in Emacs?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Add the following to your `$HOME/.emacs`:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

The next time you start Emacs, the welcome screen shouldn't appear. If you already have Emacs open with the welcome screen, you can kill it with <kbd>C-x k</kbd> (Control-x, then k).

Comment: That's the ticket. Note that inhibit-splash-screen is a relatively new name for the variable (can't remember if it's emacs 22 or 23 that introduced it). Before that, use inhibit-startup-message as Bastien says.

Comment: Actually you can just kill it by pressing `q`.

Answer (score 29):

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

Alternatively you could:

```
alias emacs='emacs --no-splash'
```

Comment: My `emacs` says that `inhibit-splash-screen` is an alias for `inhibit-startup-screen`.

Comment: In fact both `inhibit-splash-screen` `inhibit-startup-message` are just aliases for `inhibit-startup-screen`.

Comment: Bear in mind that you'll need to do this for every shell you use. IMO you're better off configuring the editor properly to begin with, good quickfix suggestion though.

Answer (score 19):

You can easily do it through emac's menus...

Options -> customize emacs -> top-level customization group

then select environment group, then initialization, and set inhibit startup screen to on.

Comment: I am using Emacs in terminal. I do not have those menus. How can I do the same without menus?

Comment: You can always reach the menu even when running Emacs in terminal, just press `F10` or type `M-x menu-bar-open`.

Answer (score 6):

In Emacs 24, `inhibit-splash-screen` and `inhibit-startup-message` are alias for `inhibit-startup-screen`, so simply add `(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)`  to your `.emacs` file will solve the problem.

Given that configuration, your startup buffer is now `*scratch*`, if you want to further change the default buffer, `M-h v initial-buffer-choice <RET>` will help.

Official document: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html

Answer (score 5):

In my .emacs I have 
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
and that works for me.

The gnu emacs manual says inhibit-startup-message is the old version and inhibit-splash-screen is the newer version. I don't know in which version that changed. 
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use set `initial-scratch-message` variable to nil to hide the initial message or set anything you want to display your message.

`(setq initial-scratch-message nil)`

or

`(setq initial-scratch-message ";; Happy Hacking")`

Hope it helped.