# P4CONFIG with emacs

Tags: emacs, perforce

I would like to see examples of how to setup perforce, using the [config file functionality](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/cmdref/env.P4CONFIG.html#1040647) where emacs is used as the diff and merge programs (P4DIFF and P4MERGE settings). Even better if this is on Windows.

I'm also struggling with getting the P4EDITOR to work correctly when using emacsclientw, specifically specifying the alternate-editor functionality.

Any tips, suggestions, example configs are very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're already using [p4.el](http://p4el.sourceforge.net/).

Here's a function that will allow you to set your p4-client-config easily:

```
(defun p4-go (config)
  (interactive
   (list (read-file-name "P4 Config file: "
                         (concat (getenv "HOME") "/etc/perforce/")
                         ""
                         t)))
  (p4-set-client-config (expand-file-name config))
  t)
```

Then I just run `M-x p4-go <RET> conf <RET>`.

My ~/etc/perforce/conf file looks like:

```
P4CLIENT=ewarmenhoven-ppd
P4PORT=perforce.netflix.com:1666
P4USER=ewarmenhoven

P4EDITOR=emacsclient
P4DIFF=diff -dupU8
P4MERGE=~/bin/emerge
```

The `emerge` merge program is just a short little shell script that calls `emacsclient` appropriately:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

base=$1
sccs=$2
mine=$3
merg=$4

emacsclient -e "(ediff-merge-files-with-ancestor \"$base\" \"$sccs\" \"$mine\" () \"$merg\")"
emacsclient "$merg"

If you're using cygwin it should work just fine.

For doing diffs, if it's running from the shell then I want the output in the shell, hence just using normal diff. If it's not, I use `p4-ediff`, which is bound to `C-x p -` by default.

Comment: Thanks Eric - I'm not actually using p4.el at the moment. Been trying to use p4 more from the command line instead of p4v so just went to PS instead of emacs - now that you say it, I probably should have stayed in emacs.

Comment: Also, thanks for the script. Loads of info. Unfortunately, I'm not using cygwin these days, as I've migrated to powershell, but I might try to adapt your script to a powershell one.

Comment: You don't need p4-go to change clients.  I just put client-variables at the root of the source tree in that directory, e.g. /var/p4/TOT/p4env (/var/p4/pvt_branch/p4env etc).  I just export P4CONFIG=p4env in my .bashrc.  Now if I open a file in /var/p4/TOT/src/test.c, perforce automatically applies the p4env from TOT.  This is true for p4 utility too.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different trick I used to use. It adds a few command line options to emacs so that you can do diffs and merges in a new emacs instance (again using ediff).

```
;; -diff
(defun command-line-diff (switch)
  (let ((file1 (pop command-line-args-left))
        (file2 (pop command-line-args-left)))
    (ediff file1 file2)))
(add-to-list 'command-switch-alist '("-diff" . command-line-diff))

;; -merge
(defun command-line-merge (switch)
  (let ((base (pop command-line-args-left))
        (sccs (pop command-line-args-left))
        (mine (pop command-line-args-left))
        (merg (pop command-line-args-left)))
   (ediff-merge-with-ancestor sccs mine base () merg)))
(add-to-list 'command-switch-alist '("-merge" . command-line-merge))
```

Just put that in your .emacs file. Then you can set your P4DIFF program to be `emacs -diff` and your P4MERGE program to be `emacs -merge`.

Comment: Awesome - I'd seen reference to emacs -diff before but nothing about how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The awesome answer by Eric doesn't work properly in latest emacs because of welcome screen. In order to hide the welcome screen (so that you may get the diff properly) please refer [Unable to hide welcome screen in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744672/unable-to-hide-welcome-screen-in-emacs).

Another nifty setting which opens the diff in regular vertical mode is setting the below config variable

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom -- don't edit or cut/paste it!
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 '(ediff-split-window-function (quote split-window-horizontally)))
```