# How do I kill the *GNU Emacs* buffer when emacs starts?

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to hide welcome screen in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744672/unable-to-hide-welcome-screen-in-emacs)

Is there a way I can prevent the *GNU Emacs* buffer from coming up when emacs starts?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744672/unable-to-hide-welcome-screen-in-emacs

Answer (score 18):

I believe this in your `~/.emacs` will do that

```
;; no startup msg  
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)        ; Disable startup message
```

Comment: inhibit-startup-message is an alias for inhibit-startup-screen

Answer (score 7):

The following in your .emacs will do the trick.

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```